# mysql join add new column

Tags: php, mysql

How can change the query so it also adds the surname column from 'updatepersonal' table? it sounds so simple but it doesnt seem to be working. I tried using a full outer join with the patientId?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
$query = "select ts.theTime,d.doctorName, 
bMon.id as bMon, bTue.id as bTue, bWed.id as bWed, bThu.id as bThu, bFri.id as bFri 
from timeSlots ts 
cross join doctors d 
left join booking bMon 
on bMon.apptDate=@Monday and bMon.timeSlotId=ts.id and bMon.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bTue 
on bTue.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 1 DAY) and bTue.timeSlotId=ts.id and bTue.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bWed 
on bWed.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 2 DAY) and bWed.timeSlotId=ts.id and bWed.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bThu 
on bThu.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 3 DAY) and bThu.timeSlotId=ts.id and bThu.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bFri 
on bFri.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 4 DAY) and bFri.timeSlotId=ts.id and bFri.doctorId=d.doctorId 
cross join (select @Monday:='2015-11-30') params 
order by ts.theTime,d.doctorName;";
```

Schema:

```
create table doctors 
(   doctorId int(4) primary key,
doctorName varchar(20) not null
);

create table timeSlots 
(
id int auto_increment primary key,
theTime time not null
);

insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('09:00:00');    -- 1
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('10:00:00');    -- 2
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('11:00:00');    -- 3
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('12:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('13:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('14:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('15:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('16:00:00');
insert into timeSlots (theTime) values ('17:00:00');    -- 9

create table booking
(   surname varchar(20),
id int auto_increment primary key,
patientId int not null,
amORpm varchar(2),
doctorName varchar(20),
altamORpm varchar(1),
altdate varchar(1),
altdoctor varchar(1),
date date,
doctorId int not null,
apptTime time,
booked varchar(1)
apptDate date not null,
timeSlotId int not null,
doctorId int(4),
key(apptDate) -- index
);

create table updatepersonal (
surname varchar(20),
id int(4),
forename varchar(20),
DOB datetime,
doctorId  int not null,
contactno char(11),
email varchar(40),
address varchar(100),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: What field do you have to use to join updatepersonal table to any of the other tables?

Comment: patientId? i basically need it be another column after Friday to have all the surnames of the patients. do you get what im trying to say? i don't think it made much sense in my question ^^ lol :/ @Shadow

Comment: I basically need it add another column after 'Friday' in my result table to have all the surnames of the patients from the booking table.